# Is the editing function broken?

Tags: support, reputation, editing

I was cruising the front page, and ran into [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/140832/is-it-ok-to-run-perfmon-on-production-servers-and-why/140983#140983).  A user with 67 rep edited an answer.  According to the [privileges page](https://serverfault.com/privileges) and my own recollection, you shouldn't be able to do that until you have 2000 rep.  Now in this case, no harm no foul.  But if this is accurate, it needs to be looked at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll have to look up the reference, but any user can *suggest* edits. These are put into a queue visible to 10K(?)+ users to approve as appropriate. Once an edit is approved, it is recorded as if that user made the edit.

Comment: [Here's the link from the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/)

Comment: So I'm clearly not paying attention... Well at least it was a recent change.  Thanks!

Comment: Anyone who as sufficient rep to edit without approval can approve a suggested edit. You have to have >10k rep to have them made easy to find.

Comment: Thanks! You can tell an edit is pending if the edit link reads "edit(0)".

Comment: Also, high rep users can see the suggestion and who approved it, in this case "Approved 22 hours ago by Mark Henderson"